# Word meaning 'resistant to temperature change'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the property of liquids that means the liquid has a high resistance to temperature change. The closest thing I've found is ['high specific heat capacity'](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/earth501/content/p5_p9.html) but it's a one-word term. I heard it on a science TV show I was watching and I can't remember what the word was.

**Clarification**:  I mean it takes a lot of energy to change the temperature. but the word I'm looking for means specifically that the liquid has a high specific heat capacity

Comment: Non-conductive?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by a high resistance to temperature change?  Do you mean that it takes a lot of energy to raise the temperature?  If so, then the term is high specific heat capacity.  Period.  If you mean that the liquid maintains some property even if its temperature changes greatly, then perhaps one of the answers suits you.

Comment: yes i mean it takes a lot of energy to change the temperature. but the word i'm looking for means specifically that the liquid has a **high** specific heat capacity.

Comment: "High specific heat" is about as good as you can expect to do.

Comment: Though note that you could achieve the high specific heat capacity by employing an *endothermic* chemical reaction of some sort.

Comment: @HotLicks you're probably right. for some reason i remember hearing a single word meaning this on TV one time...

Answer (score 2):

"Thermostable"; also, more scientifically, "having a high specific heat."

***thermostable*** -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thermostable)

> (adj.) 1. Physically or chemically unaffected by high temperatures

Comment: The word DOES NOT fit your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact fit but see **eurythermal**, defined by [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eurythermic) as

> Tolerating a wide range of temperature.

Also, you can see related words such as [thermoduric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thermoduric) and [extremophile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extremophile).